# Migrate Desktop Swing CRUD Client to Web Application Netbeans 7.2 Glassfish 3.1.2

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, ejb, glassfish-3

What tools are available in Netbeans or elsewhere to migrate a simple Java CRUD client app to web app preserving at least a resemblance of the original design?

The desktop client app connects to EJB served by Glassfish.

Using Netbeans new project wizard, I generated the Web Service connecting it to the EJB service that serves the client app , and web service test page has most of the methods that I would need to call. Most of the methods work already, all that is missing is layout and some buttons.

All of the code is under one big enterprise project.

Basically, I do not want to recreate the original client app design from scratch again.

Comment: Which front end technology will you use ?

Comment: I am pretty open to suggestions here. :) I was just hoping for something quick and dirty. It is literally just buttons and some text fields, and ok one checkbox... I tried to set up with Primefaces, but something was broken in Netbeans generated build. I am quite experienced in server side Javascript and C, but much less so in regular Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention why you're converting to a web app.  If the only reason is so that your app is accessible from the web, then you can deploy your existing app via [Java Web Start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/index.html) with little effort.

Comment: Thanks, this looks even easier than I thought, strange that I have not seen many instances of Web Start in real life.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out this webinar on creating web based apps (with the same purpose as your business swing app) with NetBeans and Glassfish: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3TompuzySD8

In this video we're using the open source Vaadin framework (Disclaimer: I am a developer on this project) for creating the UIs. The most relevant starting point for you would probably be https://vaadin.com/swing

Comment: In this Vaadin approach the really good thing is you don't need JVMin your end users browser or even in the OS at all. Pretty much no OSs install Java by default anymore (java is mostly the server side language nowadays) and in e.g. tablets this is typically not even possible.